# How to create this type of ui i am facing a issue while scrolling the view

Tags: android

[image]

This is the ui which i have to create . I need scrolling when user fill the edit text but the button has to stay at the bottom . the whole view get mixed up please help me  . view will scroll and all ui will be not collapse

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/frag_login_edt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        
             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/frag_login_edt_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frag_login_edt_email"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
          />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_30"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frag_login_edt_password"
            android:id="@+id/frag_login_tv_forgot_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/frag_login_txt_forgot_password"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <include
            layout="@layout/social_integration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/frag_login_button_continue_as_guest"
            android:id="@+id/include" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
            android:id="@+id/frag_login_button_continue_as_guest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
                       android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_above="@+id/include"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
            android:id="@+id/button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


INclude Code thcode is common so i include it


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_login_ll_or"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/frag_view_one"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_30"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frag_view_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/frag_view_one"
            android:text="OR" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/frag_view_two"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frag_login_ll_or"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/google" />

    
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

THis is activity\

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@drawable/bg">

          
            <include
                layout="@layout/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.3">

            <include layout="@layout/view_pager" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: In short You need an Activity with a ViewPager that contains two Fragments. You need also a TabLayout connected to the Viewpager to show the tabs. The Fragment as "shown" in your image could implement a  LinearLayout(vertical) to dispose the single UI elements

Comment: yes with scrolling because when user enter something in the edit text the softinput open and the button disturbed they mixed up